# mongodb full text search for multiple phrases

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

if this is possible to search multiple phrases in mongodb?

for ex:

```
db.words.insert({name:"john cooper"})
db.words.insert({name:"mike spelman"})
```

and i need to find "john cooper" and "mike spelman"

i can to create query with single phrase:

```
db.words.find({$text:{$search : "\"mike serpsky\" john cooper"}})
```

and get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f01b2c827e16e12f6eeebf"), "name" : "mike serpsky" }
```

but i can't create next query:

```
db.words.find({$text:{$search : "\"mike serpsky\" \"john cooper\""}})
```

if exist something way to do this in single query?

Comment: Umm. You do realize you are using "exact phrases" that do not match your supplied example data. If you just do: `db.words.find({ "$text": { "$search": "mike john" } })` then everything works just fine.

Comment: yes, single phrase works fine - but i have array of phrases ..

Comment: It's **not** and "OR" query. Simple to understand?

Comment: yes, and i ask for solutions

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Full text search not really helpful in this case. 
Solution founded with regular expressions:

```
db.words.find({"name": {$in : [/john cooper/, /mike serpsky/]}})
```

or

```
db.words.find({"name": /john cooper|mike serpsky/})
```

both works fine.